# Como criar um campo que faz referencia à um sub-array de uma collection no mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Imaginando a seguinte estrutura(Exemplo meramente ilustrativo):

***Collection: Escolas***

```
[
   {
      "_id":"abc123",
      "nomeEscola":"escola1",
      "turmas":{
         "_id":"ccc333",
         "nomeTurma":"Turma1"
      }
   },
   {
      "_id":"abc122",
      "nomeEscola":"escola2",
      "turmas":{
         "_id":"ddd444",
         "nomeTurma":"Turma1"
      }
   }
]
```

Agora, digamos que eu vá criar uma nova collection de alunos, e eu queira o schema dela no mongoose tenha o `ID` da `TURMA` e ***não*** da `ESCOLA`

***AlunoModel:***

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let alunoSchema = new Schema({
    _id : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId},
    nomeAluno : {type: String},
    idTurma: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Escolas'},
},  {collection : 'Alunos'});


var aluno = mongoose.model('Aluno', alunoSchema);

module.exports = aluno;
```

> Como eu faço para garantir que `idTurma` vá referenciar o id da Turma e não o id da Escola?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom dia!
Só precisa referenciar o atributo do documento que será referenciado.

```
idTurma: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Escolas.turmas'}
```

Vendo seu schema de alunos, você pode omitir o atributo _id, ele é gerado automaticamente na hora que você salva um documento na base..
Caso você queira atribuir o _id dele, antes da inserção no banco, você pode fazer atribuir o valor do _id direto.

```
let ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId; 
aluno = new Aluno()
aluno._id = ObjectId()
```

Beijos

Comment: muito obrigado!